# Rounding values less than 1 in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

I am coding a graphical program in C and my cartesian values are in between [-1,1], I am having trouble rounding off values so that I can use them for plotting and further calculations. I know how to round values greater than 1 with decimals but this I haven't done before.

So how would I go about rounding values? For example,

```
.7213=.7

.7725= .8

.3666667=.4

.25=.2 or .3

.24=.2
```

Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated. :)

Comment: None of `.2`, `.3`, `.4`, `.7`, `.8` is representable as a binary floating-point number (at any precision), so it is pointless to round to something close (but not exactly equal) to these values. You may want to convert to decimal with 1 digit after the dot at the very end for the sake of the user. This is a different proposition. It is achieved with `printf("%.1f", …);`

Comment: You can't. Floating point values don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and they aren't commensurable.

Comment: @EJP Does C require floating point to have binary places?  I thought such FP detail was implementation dependent, it could be binary or decimal, or whatever.  Certainly thought binary FP implementations are most common.

Comment: @chux Good question, but I've never seen a decimal FPU in over forty years of computing.

Comment: Used it even as far back as [C](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21751) and [Pascal](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20792) in the late 1980s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most languages, people often implement such rounding in an ad hoc way using `*10`, integral rounding, and `/10`.  For example:

```
$ cat round.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%f\n",     ((double)  ((uint64_t) (10*0.7777))) / 10);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc round.c
[tommd@Vodka Test]$ ./a.out
0.700000
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But since I will be plotting these values, .8 would more precise than .7 for .77777. Can't do anything about it?

Comment: Sure you can, it's just some basic math.  If you want "round to nearest integral" as taught in grade school then add `0.5` prior to the rounding (where "rounding" is actually truncation).

Comment: Ah.! That was a dumb question. Thanks :)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Since I am cast in a pedantic role, I should point out that in the sequence `float f = 0.050000003f; printf("%.16e %f\n", f, ((double)  ((uint64_t) (10 * f))) / 10);` where `f` is clearly shown to be above 0.05 (printed as `5.0000004470348358e-02`), your manipulation produces `0.000000`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Your code does not sufficiently communicate your point.  I see you start with a number `~0.05` and that naive integral truncation results in `0`.  Were you expecting something else?  There are many ways to "round" a number, I never formally stated which was presented.  Also, I thought to myself that you are pedantic enough that you should work on frama-c or compcert... then I saw that it appears you do ;-).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Sorry about that, I did not notice that the code I was using did not include the “add 0.5” fix from your comment. I meant `float f = 0.049999997f; printf("%.16e %f\n", f, ((double)  ((uint64_t) (10 * f + 0.5f))) / 10);`, which prints `4.9999997019767761e-02 0.100000`, where a value below 0.05 is rounded to 0.10.

Comment: +1 This is a good, practical, answer. It is silly to see people downvote it in favor of an answer that is theoretically correct but at the same time is entirely useless to the OP.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The theoretically correct answer leads to practical methods, such as retaining available accuracy until a final display is needed, adjusting the units/scale used so that the desired values can be exactly represented, et cetera. These bad answers promote bad use of floating point, perpetuating the myths and bad, buggy software. Floating point is a great benefit **when used correctly**, and that knowledge should be promoted.

Answer (score 7):

You don't (and can't, to any high degree of accuracy, due to how floating point values are stored) round floating point values, you can only output them to different degrees of precision. If you wanted all your float values rounded to 1 decimal place before using them in calculations, then do your calculations with integers, with everything multiplied by 10, then divide by 10 just before you display it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought about that, just wondering if there was a better way. :)

Comment: This is currently the most correct answer.  However, you could be generous, and interpret the OP's question as "how do I round to the nearest representable float"... ;)